# opengl stack glViewport strange behaviour

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working with modern opengl, and my goal is to debug a viewing frustum culling. In order to achieve this, I created another viewport, so I can look at my entire model and my frustum moving while I'm moving in my principal program.

It works, but there is still a strange behaviour I don't understand... 
my viewport are :

```
glViewport(0,0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
//render my program with motionned camera
glViewport(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2, screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2)
//render my MotionLess Camera
```

Since I'm stacking them, I'm wondering if it creates an undefined behavior? Because my result isn't what I expected. (Here's the better draw you'll see ever! : )

[image]

In fact, What I thought is that my screen would be like the part red and darker red => My program is rendered on the red part, and my motionless camera on the darker red. But the yellow part appeared => My motionned camera is rendered on the red screen, it's ok. But my motionless camera is rendered in the yellow part, and the rest of the darker red is black.

I show you with my real example :

[image]

Do you know from where does it come from?

** EDIT : ** As datenwolf mentionned, my problem is due to the face that I'm rendering to FBO. And it seems that you do not want to use a glViewport offset other than (0,0) when you render in FBO (see this : [HereIsAnAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072578/opengl-rendering-to-texture-by-using-fbo-and-viewport-offset-problems)).

Answer (score 3):

> (…) Since I'm stacking them, (…)

OpenGL viewports don't stack. Each call to `glViewport` replaces whatever viewport has been set before.

*(EDIT):* Also the viewport doesn't necessarily clip geometry that transforms outside of it, i.e. if the viewport is only a portion of the window then stuff "outside" of the viewport might still be visible. To make sure that you're actually clipping stuff outside the viewport, you have to combine it with *scissor testing* (`glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)`) and set the scissor rectangle to match with the viewport using `glScissor(…)`.

Comment: So, my first `glViewport` is all my screen, and my second viewport would be the quarter of my screen. The problem isn't coming from here. Is it what you are saying?
I'll take a look at `glScissor`!

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch: Also make sure that you clear the depth buffer for rendering the smaller viewport (otherwise whatever is in the depth buffer there will interfere with what is going to be rendered there). glScissor also limits buffer clears (unlike just glViewport).

Comment: Well, glClear doesn't do anything :/

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch: Without seeing your actual code it's very hard to give any other sensible advice. How about you try to create a MCVE. A little program that exactly reproduces the problem without being your full project.

Comment: Yeah, knowing my skills, I wouldn't be able to create an MCVE. 
But I think I found something that can be the problem : When I generate my second FBO, I use the screenWidth and the ScreenHeight. I should probably use screenWidth/2 and screenHeight/2. doing so, it only render black! and when I use screenWidth /4 and screenheight/4, it render only a little window...

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch: Oh, you're rendering to an FBO? Well, then you probably **do not** want a nonzero xy viewport offset when rendering to that.

Comment: Oh? 
Yeah, I'm rendering the 2 views to FBO's. It didn't know it... What can I do. If I can't use nonzero xy viewport offset? And why? That's strange :o

Comment: ... Ok, instead of `glViewport(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2, screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2)`, I used `glViewPort(0,0,screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2)` And It worked. I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072578/opengl-rendering-to-texture-by-using-fbo-and-viewport-offset-problems, But I don't understand really well yet what happened x)

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch: A FBO is just another "window" (private to the OpenGL context and invisible) and the viewport defines *where* in the window the projection space should map to. So if you want to render into some small corner inside of the FBO then you place the viewport there. But if you want to cover the whole FBO then the viewport must of course cover the whole FBO. OpenGL is a state machine and lives in the moment and glViewport does affect *drawing operations* not some encompassing "big picture".

Answer (score -1):

This looks like somewhere you are rendering with clip space coordinates from `0..1` instead of `-1..+1` (assuming that the "yellow" error part is what you want to appear across the whole of the dark red part).

So maybe in the vertex shader, you need to scale your vertices by 2 and subtract 1 to move from 0..1 coordinates to -1..+1 coordinates?

Also, it's `glViewport()`, but it's probably just a typo in the question.

Documentation on clip space and other coordinate systems used in OpenGL:

https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems

Comment: Totally a typo. Sorry :/
Well, that's strange since i'm using same shader for motionned camera part and motionless camera part. Only giving another camera (and here, I'm not rendering the same texture. But shaders are the same.